# Validating PasswordResetToken for ResetPassword

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, forgot-password, reset-password

I am trying to create manual Reset Password on ForgetPassword token click. But when I validate this token with user, it always returns false.
Please help me in this
here is my code

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> ResetPassword()
{
    var provider = new DpapiDataProtectionProvider("AppName");
    var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>());
    userManager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(provider.Create("EmailConfirmation"));
    string userId = Request.QueryString["UserId"];
    string code = Request.QueryString["code"];
    var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
    //if (!(await UserManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(userId, code)).Succeeded)
    ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();
    UserStore<ApplicationUser> store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
    if (!await userManager.UserTokenProvider.ValidateAsync("EmailConfirmation", code, new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(store) , user))
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Message", "Home", new { status = false, message = "Invalid token, please retry." });
    }
    return View("ResetPassword", new ResetPasswordModel { UserId = userId, Token = code });
}
```

Also this is the code how I generate PasswordResetToken

```
var provider = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataProtection.DpapiDataProtectionProvider("AppName");
UserManager.UserTokenProvider = new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(provider.Create("EmailConfirmation"));
var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
if (user == null)//|| !(await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id)))
{
    // Don't reveal that the user does not exist or is not confirmed
    return Json(new { status = false, message = "User does not exist" });
}
var code = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);
```

Please help me in this

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps a bit late, but I recently ran into a similar requirement.

The only issue I see is

```
if (!await userManager.UserTokenProvider.ValidateAsync("EmailConfirmation", code, new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(store) , user))
{
    return RedirectToAction("Message", "Home", new { status = false, message = "Invalid token, please retry." });
}
```

Change this to

```
if (!await userManager.UserTokenProvider.ValidateAsync("ResetPassword", code, new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(store) , user))
{
    return RedirectToAction("Message", "Home", new { status = false, message = "Invalid token, please retry." });
}
```

"**EmailConfirmation**" will be used with the registration email, while "**PasswordReset**" is used for the ForgotPassword goodies.